# Is there a way to specify "optional" packages in conda's environment.yml file?

Tags: python, conda

In my repos I often like to have two different virtual environments, one that is as lean as possible and the other containing a lot of useful packages for debug. Of course I can create two separate environment.yml files and activate the desired environment at each time but I wonder if there is a way to condense the information about necessary and optional packages in one file to avoid duplication and eventual inevitable inconsistencies between the two.

Ideally, I would love to have something like that in environment.yml

```
name: MyEnv

channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults

dependencies:
 - python=3.10
 - numpy

optional:
 - seaborn
 - matplotlib
```

with a command like

```
conda env create -f environment.yml --install_optional
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not a thing.** Consider posting as a feature request on [the Conda repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).

Comment: :( Thanks. I found an open issue requesting the same feature https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12098